# Sorting of files while reading from document directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am currently reading the list of files present in my app document directory.

```
NSString* documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];  
NSError* error = nil;
NSMutableArray  *myArray = (NSMutableArray*)[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentDirectory error:&error]retain];
```

But before showing the list of files i want to show the all files should be sorted properly.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your myArray will be an array of NSStrings. Since they are all in the same directory you can sort it like this:

```
NSArray * sortedArray =
 [myArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Now it is important to note that `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentDirectory error:&error` returns both directories and files. So before getting the sorted array, if you want just files,

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSString *str in myArray)
{
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:str]
[tempArray addObject:str];
}
```

Now sort this tempArray instead of myArray and you're done

Comment: do you know how to maintain the same order as in the directory? As far as I can see the array get filled with ascending order of the file names.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSSortDescriptor on your array and enumerate. [This](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/SortDescriptors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000174i) is an excellent place to learn in detail on how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

For a `NSMutableArray` just use `sortUsingSelector` with the built-in sector `compare:`.
Ex:

```
[myArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

to sort your Array you can do just.

```
        NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];// for descending sort you can set the parameter ascending to NO.

        NSArray* sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```